# using hammerjs with translate3d... resets to 0

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

```
ready = ->
  transform = {}

  handlePan = (ev) ->
    el = $(".actions[data-object='" + ev.target.dataset.object + "']")
    el.removeClass('accept').addClass('reject') if ev.deltaX < 0
    el.removeClass('reject').addClass('accept') if ev.deltaX > 0
    transform.translate = { x: ev.deltaX }
    updateElementTransform(ev.target.dataset.object)

  updateElementTransform = (obj) ->
    value = [
      'translate3d(' + transform.translate.x + 'px, 0px, 0)'
    ]
    value = value.join(" ")
    el = document.querySelector(".vehicle[data-object='" + obj + "']")
    el.style.webkitTransform = value
    el.style.mozTransform = value
    el.style.transform = value

  createHammer = (v) ->
    mc = new Hammer.Manager(v, {})
    mc.add new Hammer.Pan(
      direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL
      threshold: 0
    )
    mc.on 'panleft', handlePan
    mc.on 'panright', handlePan

  selector = '.market-place .vehicle'
  createHammer(v) for v in document.querySelectorAll(selector)

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

So, after I move an item with this... it stays where I leave it. But if I try to grab it again, when I start moving it, it starts from 'zero', not where I left it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `ev.deltaX` refers to the current gesture. You can save its value on pan end and then add it when calculating translation.

something like:

```
var totalDeltaX = 0;

mc.on('pan', function(e){
    // translateX = totalDeltaX + e.deltaX  ...
});

mc.on('panend', function(e){
    // totalDeltaX += e.deltaX ...
});
```